# ScrapySplash start_urls and other fields from MYSQL Database ( orCSV)

Tags: mysql, csv, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to pull url field plus two other fields from MySQL database using ScrapySplash. I can get the URL and crawling to work OK but I am not able to get the 2 other fields thatshould be corresponding to the url being crawled. Here is my latest attempt

`dataReader()` has three items in it urls are at index[0] and pull perfectly with `self.start_urls[0]`

However, I am not able to pull the corresponding row data from index[1] for  `itemid` or from index[2] for `location`

I am guessing it has to do with the meta statement or the for loop. It would make more sense to have the for statement not use the [0] option but then any other way, I could not get it to crawl

**myscrapy.py**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import MyScrapyItem
from .readdata import dataReader
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class my_scrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_scrapy"
    allowed_domains = ['www.google.com']
    start_urls = dataReader()


    script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
            splash.private_mode_enabled = false
            assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
            assert(splash:wait(15))
            return {
            splash:html()
            }
            end
    '''

    def start_requests(self):
        # create initial requests for urls in start_urls
        for url in self.start_urls[0]:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute", args={
                'lua_source': self.script, 'wait': 5
            }, meta={"itemid": self.start_urls[1], "locationid": self.start_urls[2]})


    def parse(self, response):
        items = MyScrapyItem()
        itemid = response.meta['itemid']
        locationid= response.meta['locationid']
        #print(response.data)
        
        chairs = response.xpath('//div[3]//div[1]//h4[1]//span[1]//span[1]/text()').extract()
        tables = response.xpath('//div[2]//div[1]//h4[1]//span[1]//span[1]/text()').extract()
        

        items['itemid'] = itemid
        items['locationid'] = locationid

        
        items['chairs'] = chairs
        items['table'] = table

        yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

This works!!!

by defining each of the columns being yielded by readdata() function:

```
start_urls = dataReader()
starturls = dataReader()[0]
itemids = dataReader()[1]
locationids = dataReader()[2]
```

and using range(len.. as loop for the starturls as well as the meta values for the 2 other columns that are being pulled from readdata()

```
def start_requests(self):
        # create initial requests for urls in start_urls
        for url in range(len(self.starturls)):
            yield SplashRequest(url=self.starturls[url], callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute", args={
                'lua_source': self.script, 'wait': 5
            }, meta={"itemid": self.itemids[url], "locationid": self.locationids[url]})
```

Comment: You should add an explanation as to why this works and why the OPs code is not correct

Comment: @msenior_ edited to clarify why it works